Validate Protocol-Relative URLs
I'm trying to determine whether a URL is absolute or not, but it seems the URI object doesn't validate protocol-relative URLs, it only validates whether it contains a scheme.
I want to avoid an open redirect for security reasons and therefore want to catch protocol-relative URls to avoid redirecting to them.
https://www.fastly.com/blog/open-redirects-real-world-abuse-and-recommendations/

    /**
     * Checks whether the provided URL string is absolute or not
     * @param url the URL in string format
     * @return true if the provided string is absolute, else returns false
     * @throws URISyntaxException if unable to create a URI from the provided string
     */
    private static boolean isAbsoluteURL(final String url) throws URISyntaxException {
        return new URI(url).isAbsolute();
    }

Is there a way to also identity protocol-relative URLs like this?
//hackerone.com\@www.example.com
I could do a basic regex to check if contains // but doesn't seem right so maybe there's a Java library that already does this?

Doesn't look like the JDK supports this. So ... uri.startsWith("//")?

Yeah that was my backup option (appreciate the response btw!) if no library for this exists.

Well it might. Just not in the jDK itself
